# How to randomly removing n edges without disconnecting graph using python

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm using networkx package, how can I randomly remove multiple edges but not causing any disconnection(nodes number be the same).

I've tried Stratified sampling the dataframe, but not working, don't know how to do it.
please for any advice.

here how I do so:

```
removed_edge_cnt = 0
remove_list = set([])
pbar = tqdm(total=n)
while (removed_edge_cnt < n):
    removed = True
    drop_indices = np.random.choice(orig_data_copy.index, 1, replace=False)
    edge = orig_data_copy.iloc[drop_indices, :].values.ravel()
    orig_data_copy = orig_data_copy.drop(drop_indices)  # 不管該邊有沒有要刪掉都要drop避免一直取相同的edge
    # print('{}-{}:{}'.format(edge[0], edge[1], G.has_edge(edge[0], edge[1])))
    if G.has_edge(edge[0], edge[1]):  # 邊存在
        G.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
        if not nx.is_weakly_connected(G):  # 移除是否會造成disconnect
            G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
            removed = False
        if removed:
            removed_edge_cnt += 1
            remove_list.add((edge[0], edge[1]))
            pbar.update(1)
pbar.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I do not explain my question well. I have a CSV file containing a list of edge, and I was trying to split it into 3 part such as train, validation, and test, but I want to make sure that each graph remains the same nodes, because random split may cause each graph to have a different node-set.

Answer (score 0):

A completely connected graph is one where there is a path from every node to every other.  I assume that this is what you mean by "no disconnection"

To check if a graph is completely connected, do a depth first search from any node and confirm that every node is visited.

So, remove your random edges(s) and check if the graph is still completely connected.  If not, replace the links and try again until you find an edge that can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've thought of this method, my thought is to check wcc every time when removing an edge, but I have a really large graph, so I was seeking a faster way to do so.

Comment: I notice that you are using python.  If you really care about speed, you should change to C++ - your algorithm will run many times faster.

Comment: Have you done a performance test?  How long does your code take to check for completeness?  If you share your graph, I can run my code on it and we can compare performance.

Comment: I'm using amazon data for the test(https://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon0601.html), it takes almost one second for removing an edge and I was trying to remove one-fourth of the total edge, so it probably needs 137 hours...

Comment: That certainly is a big graph!  Doing a complete DFS on it in one second is very impressive.  Perhaps you are using a compiled C++ library with a python interface?

Comment: Running my C++ DFS on the SNAP amazon0601 graph takes 0.505 seconds.